# Converting inches into feet and inches

Tags: java

I am currently taking a introduction to programming class and have reached a problem. I have been asked to convert a height measurement from inches to feet & inches.

I have gotten to the point were I think I mostly have it but I get a not a statement error when I go to compile. Here is what I have so far for this method

```
/**
 * @param inches to feet inches
 */
public String inchToFeet(int heightInInches) {
    int IN_PER_FOOT;
    int feet = heightInInches - IN_PER_FOOT;
    String output;

    feet = feet / 12;
    output = String; inchToFeet() + "\'" + IN_PER_FOOT.toString() + "\"";
    return output;
}
```

I am also using a static final int to keep the inches per foot constrained to 12, like this.

```
public static final int IN_PER_FOOT = 12;
```

This is really the only issue I am having at the moment, the rest it just getting it along with a hourly rate to display.

Edit:

The compile error I keep getting is 'Not a Statement'. I have also removed the semicolon from before the last String but got another error as it was looking for the semicolon.

I will try your suggestion in a little Rahul, been looking at this for to long and need a break.

Comment: Your code is currently all over the place. You're declaring a local variable called `IN_PER_FOOT` which you're not assigning a value to, you're trying to subtract it from `heightInInches` for no obvious reason; you're trying to set `output` to just `String` (????) and you're trying to call `inchToFeet` without any arguments for no obvious reason. You really need to start this method from scratch, IMO...

Comment: So, do you want us to comment on the compilation error, which you haven't posted, or the fact that this code won't do what you expect?

Comment: This will let you compile at least `output = inchToFeet() + " \ " + IN_PER_FOOT + " \ ";`

Answer (score 7):

Your code doesnt seem to work what you want. You may simply try like this:-

```
int inches = 40;
int feet = inches / 12;
int leftover = inches % 12;
System.out.println(feet + " feet and " + leftover + " inches");
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'm still getting an error but I shall try this in a while after a take a break.

Answer (score 0):

After Searching on StackOverflow and another website I made Ft->cm and cm->ft by combining 2-3 answers.
Can come in handy

```
   fun feetToCentimeter(feetval: String): String {
            var heightInFeet = 0.0
            var heightInInches = 0.0
            var feet = ""
            var inches = ""
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(feetval)) {
                if (feetval.contains("'")) {
                    feet = feetval.substring(0, feetval.indexOf("'"))
                }
                if (feetval.contains("\"")) {
                    inches = feetval.substring(feetval.indexOf("'") + 1, feetval.indexOf("\""))
                }
            }
            try {
                if (feet.trim { it <= ' ' }.isNotEmpty()) {
                    heightInFeet = feet.toDouble()
                }
                if (inches.trim { it <= ' ' }.isNotEmpty()) {
                    heightInInches = inches.toDouble()
                }
            } catch (nfe: NumberFormatException) {
            }
    
            return (((heightInFeet * 12.0) + heightInInches) * 2.54).toString()
        }
    
        fun centimeterToFeet(centemeter: String?): String {
            var feetPart = 0
            var inchesPart = 0
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(centemeter)) {
                val dCentimeter = java.lang.Double.valueOf(centemeter!!)
                feetPart = Math.floor((dCentimeter / 2.54) / 12).toInt()
                println(dCentimeter / 2.54 - feetPart * 12)
                inchesPart = Math.floor((dCentimeter / 2.54) - (feetPart * 12)).toInt()
            }
            return String.format("%d' %d\"", feetPart, inchesPart)
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this code

```
int inches = 40;
int feet = (int)inches / 12;
int leftover =(int) inches % 12;
System.out.println(feet + " feet and " + leftover + " inches");
```

Comment: It's the same as above answer